# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iteritems' when trying to create Seaborn graph

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I recently upgraded my Pandas to 2.1.1 and am now getting the error above in the title when trying to create a Seaborn FacetGrid. Before upgrading I had no issue creating the graph. Due to work reasons I am not able to downgrade my Pandas version in order to get my code to work.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(file, col="fraud_or_not", margin_titles=True, sharey=False)
g.map(sns.histplot, "card_age", bins=100)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: This has been fixed in seaborn >= 0.12.1

Answer (score 0):

(iteritems)[https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html] has been deprecated for `items`.

You can try monkey patching:

```py
file.iteritems = file.items
g = sns.FacetGrid(file, col="fraud_or_not", margin_titles=True, sharey=False)
g.map(sns.histplot, "card_age", bins=100)
```

Comment: I still got the error even after doing file.iteritems = file.items